# Div Position based on (Even/Odd) Date

Tags: javascript, html

I have two `div`s with `id = "even-date"` and `id = "odd-date"`.

If today's date is even, then the `div#even-date` position should be first, and the `div#odd-date` position should be second.

If today's date is odd, then the `div#odd-date` position should be first, and the `div#even-date` position should be second.

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="even-date">
        <p>Today is Even Date</p>
    </div>

    <div id="odd-date">
        <p>Today is Odd Date</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Somewhere I found a script which can return if its odd or even, but I am not sure of FINAL javascript which will change the position of div elements.

The javascript code which I found is

```
var time = new Date().getDate();
if (time % 2 == 0) {
      // Code to change position if even date
  } else {
      // Code to change position if odd date
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = greeting;
}
```

That's all I found. Can someone help me with a complete working script? (May be a JSFiddle)

It is not necessary to have the above JavaScript, a completely different easy solution is also fine.

Comment: What is a `greeting` and what actually you want to achieve? Change the order of div elements? Or just show the needed element?

Comment: sorry just change/shuffle the div elements position..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your concern is only display, then you can use script and css like below:

```js
function elementDirection(time) {

  if (time % 2 == 0) {
    document.getElementById("container").style.flexDirection = 'column'
  } else {
     document.getElementById("container").style.flexDirection = 'column-reverse'
  }
}

var timeEven = new Date().getDate();
var timeOdd = new Date().getDate() + 1;
elementDirection(timeEven)
setTimeout(() => {elementDirection(timeOdd)}, 1000)
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

<div id="even-date">
    <p>Today is Even Date</p>
</div>

<div id="odd-date">
    <p>Today is Odd Date</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ankush however I am not able to replicate on jsfiddle, can you please check this onece? https://jsfiddle.net/ydg80nvs/

Comment: With little bit of changes, I am able to get it to work just fine http://jsfiddle.net/vh9tpLrb/

Comment: @Indraneel Babu, glad it works for you. By seeing first jsfiddle, i think you misunderstood the arrangement of the code. Actually, first section is JS, second section is CSS and third sections is HTML. That you arranged correctly, in your second jsfiddle. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help you

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="even-date">
        <p>Today is Even Date</p>
    </div>
    <div id="odd-date">
        <p>Today is Odd Date</p>
    </div>
</div>


var date = new Date().getDate();
var oddElement = document.querySelector("#odd-date").outerHTML;
var evenElement = document.querySelector("#even-date").outerHTML;
var container = document.querySelector("#container");
if (date % 2 !== 0) {
    container.innerHTML = oddElement + evenElement;
else
    container.innerHTML = evenElement + oddElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will work fine.

```js
var time = new Date().getDate();
if (time % 2 == 0) {
    //   document.querySelector('#even-date').innerHTML = `<p>Today is ${time}</p>`;
    document.querySelector('#container').innerHTML = `<div id="even-date">
    <p>Today is Even Date</p>
</div>
<div id="odd-date">
    <p>Today is Odd Date</p>
</div>`
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#container').innerHTML = `
    <div id="odd-date">
    <p>Today is Odd Date</p>
    </div>
    <div id="even-date">
    <p>Today is Even Date</p>
  </div>`
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
                
                </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Arsalan, but I don't want to add the html via javascript, I just need to position the div's based on the even/odd date!

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your html it looks like your code expect it will add day class to each div

```
<div id="container">

<div id="even-date" class='day'>
    <p>Today is Even Date</p>
</div>

<div id="odd-date" class='day'>
    <p>Today is Odd Date</p>
</div>

</div>
```

try this for javascript it will specifty even-date or odd-date of div element

```
var time = new Date().getDate();
if (time % 2 == 0) {
      var myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('day');
      myDiv.id = 'even-date';
  } 
  else
 {
          var myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('day');
          myDiv.id = 'odd-date';
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Ansari, But some how I am not able to replicate it on jsfiddle, can you help me with what is wrong: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/2apvrde5/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the **order** of the children from the container, you could do it with **flexbox**.

```
.flex.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Change the order with `order: n` on each child.

### Example

```js
function isEven(n) {
  return n % 2 === 0 ? true : false;
}

// Change order of container children
function changeOrder(container, order) {
  // Set order to each child of the container
  Array.from(container.children).forEach((child, i) => {
    child.setAttribute("style", `order: ${order[i]}`);
  });
}

var container = document.getElementById("container");
var d = new Date().getDate();

if (isEven(d)) {
  changeOrder(container, [1, 2]);
} else {
  changeOrder(container, [2, 1]);
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="even-date">
    <p>Today is even date</p>
  </div>
  <div id="odd-date">
    <p>Today is odd date</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:**

The container must be `display: flex; flex-direction: column`, otherwise it doesn't work.